# Phoenix hot deployment static assets not using new version

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

The path to the css file in my releases doesn’t change, i.e. it still points at some old css. I’ve tried the solution to [this exrm issue](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/206) but it didn’t help. I must have done something else wrong.

Comment: Did you change the path in config.exs as described? What did you change it to?

Comment: @bitwalker, I've changed the path in prod.exs to ".". I will now change it in config.exs also.

Comment: I've change :root to "." in config.exs and made a new release. It didn't change the css though.

Comment: For every new release I run `env MIX_ENV=prod mix compile; and brunch build --production; and env MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.digest; and env MIX_ENV=prod mix release`

Comment: Could you open an issue on the exrm issue tracker (https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues)? It will be easier to work through finding the solution there.